# JQuery find works in IE but not Firefox

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pull values from an xml string using find from jQuery. It works in IE, but not in firefox.

I have the fiddle below:

```
var xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<Template xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><templateId>90</templateId><CalendarColumn>MEASUREMENT_DATE</CalendarColumn><UOMColumn>undefined</UOMColumn><Type>dial</Type></Template>";

var catalogName = $(xmlString).find('CalendarColumn').text();

alert(catalogName);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zJCfy/

If I run this in IE it will work correctly, displaying calendarColumn text. If I run this same fiddle in Firefox, I get "" returned.

JQuery shouldn't behave this way. Is this a browser settings issue?

Comment: You'r etreating your xml as if it were html.

Comment: Why does IE treat this differently?

Comment: i would have expected the opposite, but any time you use something in an unexpected way you can get unexpected results. use the `$.parseXML()` method to parse XML. Edit: guess i shoulda refreshed the page!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to parse that as XML first, and since you're using jQuery:

```
xmlString = $.parseXML(xmlString);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zJCfy/1/

API: `.parseXML` : doc: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: ++1 boooom magic, beat me by few secs yo `:)` Sorry I made minor cahnge to your post, i.e. added the Doc for the OP.